# How to add hugging face lib to a Kaggle notebook

Tags: kaggle, huggingface-transformers

How to add hugging face lib to a Kaggle notebook. I want to add [this one](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-cnn?text=hi) to my notebook . the code sample below does not work in the notebook I have. is there some additional step I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All models of the huggingface model hub are available once you install the library. This one in particular is only available in PyTorch, so you should install both `transformers` and `torch`:

```
!pip install transformers torch
```

You can then use the model:

```py
from transformers import BartForConditionalGeneration

model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-large-cnn")
```

This model is a summarization model so I would recommend reading the [summarization tutorial](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html#summarization) on Hugging Face's website.